# Gnucash How get I rid of strange unreadable characters

Tags: macos, gnucash

I installed Gnucash on my Mac OS X El Capitan, but I'm having problems with titles and headings on the interface and reports.

By following the advice on here https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Q:_How_get_I_rid_of_strange_unreadable_characters_or_adjust_the_font_size., I've managed to get rid of the problem on the interface and the headings on reports, but the problem still affects the titles of reports.

Instead of getting the title Income Statement for ..., etc, I get a long list of numbers.

Income Statement Report:

[image]

Regarding advice below (from the Gnucash wiki page)

MacOs: Create a plain text file in your home folder (~ is unix shorthand for your home folder):

X Window version: `~/.gtkrc-2.0` 
native version: `~/.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash`

I'm not a computer whizz, in fact I'm quite hopeless. I don't really understand where the home folder is or what the difference between X Window version and native version is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can make certain the `~/.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash` file mentioned in the Gnucash documentation is correct.

- Quit Gnucash if it's running.
- Open a Terminal window by clicking `Terminal` in `Launchpad`. In the Terminal window, type, or copy (<kbd>⌘C</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>⌘V</kbd>) this line:

```
cat - > ~/.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash
```

- Hit the <kbd>return</kbd> key. Nothing will happen. The `cat` command is waiting for you to type or paste some text.
- Copy these lines:

```
style "font"
{
  font_name = "Arial Narrow 12"
}
widget_class "*" style "font"
gtk-font-name = "Arial Narrow"
```

- Return to the Terminal window.
- Paste (<kbd>⌘V</kbd>).
- Type control+D (<kbd>⌃D</kbd>).

The terminal window should look like this:

[image: Terminal window]

- Quit Terminal.

The file you made is hidden from OS X Finder. It's there, but you won't see it in your home folder.

If you want to change the `.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash` file, you can use TextEdit. Select `File->Open...` from the TextEdit menu bar. Go to your home folder by typing shift+command+H (<kbd>⇧⌘H</kbd>). Type shift+command+. (<kbd>⇧⌘.</kbd>) to reveal the hidden files and open `.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash`.

I noticed from the screen snapshot that the currency setting is the Baht (฿). The `.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash` file assumes Arial Narrow will fix the font problem, but you may need to select a font that supports your language. Edit the `.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash` file to try a different font. If Thai is your language, the the Mac has these fonts that include Thai script: Arial Unicode MS, Ayuthaya, Krungthep, Sathu, Silom, Sukhumvit, and Thonburi.

Another possible problem is the locale that Gnucash is using. See [Gnucash Locale Settings](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Locale_Settings) for information.

About Mac OS X, the X Window System, and your home folder...

### Mac OS X and the X Window System

When the GnuCash documentation mentions "native version," it means the Gnucash application that you're using with Mac OS X. Apple's Mac OS X and the X Window System are entirely different. In this sense of "native," the X Window version of Gnucash is not native, that is, it's not the usual application that runs on OS X.

The [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) was created to run remote applications, meaning X lets you work from your computer directly with an application running on another computer. With the X Window System and X applications, you can run Microsoft Windows applications from a UNIX workstation, or you can run a UNIX application from an Apple Macintosh computer.

### Your home folder

Your home folder is named with your user name and has folders for your desktop files, downloads, pictures, documents, movies, music, and any public files. To see your home folder, select `Go->Home` from the Finder menu bar. You should not move or rename the folders in your home folder. These folders have special uses and are necessary for your Mac to function correctly.

For more information about OS X folders, select `Help->Mac Help` from the Finder menu bar. Search for "home folder" and click "Folders that come with your Mac". If you haven't already tried `Help->Get to Know Your Mac` from the Finder menu bar, `Get to Know Your Mac` has tips and links to `Mac Help` that answer many of the questions you may have about using your Mac.

[image: Mac Help]